# iOS localization: plurals and NSNumberFormatter

Tags: ios, objective-c, cocoa-touch

Is there a possibility to use NSNumberFormatter for NSNumber formatting together with plural rules in stringsdict?

I need to have the next *with formatted numbers* (separate thousands). If I format the number using NSNumberFormatter - I receive NSString and I can't use plural rules anymore, because iOS can't understand whether phrase is for single or plural noun from NSString.

"*1 Workout*" for single

"*1,732,123 Workouts*" for plural

```
NSNumberFormatter* numberFormatter = ...;
[NSString stringWithFormat:NSLocalizedString(@"%@ Workouts!", @"n Workout(s)"), [numberFormatter stringFromNumber:value]]
```

Answer (score 11, accepted):

After some research I found, that I can separate thousands in number without NSNumberFormatter, just using **localizedStringWithFormat**. And it also gives me the possibility to use plural rules.

```
[NSString localizedStringWithFormat:NSLocalizedString(@"%@ Workouts!", @"n Workout(s)"), value]
```

---

*Localizable.stringsdict*

```
...
<key>%@ Workouts</key>
<dict>
    <key>NSStringLocalizedFormatKey</key>
    <string>%#@Workouts@</string>
    <key>Workouts</key>
    <dict>
        <key>NSStringFormatSpecTypeKey</key>
        <string>NSStringPluralRuleType</string>
        <key>NSStringFormatValueTypeKey</key>
        <string>@</string>
        <key>one</key>
        <string>%@ Workout!</string>
        <key>other</key>
        <string>%@ Workouts!</string>
    </dict>
</dict>
....
```

Answer (score 1):

You can pass number and formatted string (2 arguments) into `NSLocalizedString`
The basic idea is to use the number to control plural rule but use the formatted string to display.

I'm using `Decimal` in Swift as an example:

```swift
let number: Decimal = 13456
let formatter: NumberFormatter = {
    let formatter = NumberFormatter()
    formatter.numberStyle = .decimal
    formatter.groupingSeparator = ","
    return formatter
}()

let formattedNumberString = formatter.string(from: number as NSDecimalNumber) ?? "-" // "13,456"

let format = NSLocalizedString(
    "workouts",
    comment: "arg1 is for number, arg2 is for formatted string"
)

let resultString = String.localizedStringWithFormat(
    format, 
    number as NSDecimalNumber, 
    formattedNumberString
)
```

In the **Localizable.stringsdict**，you can do:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<!DOCTYPE plist PUBLIC "-//Apple//DTD PLIST 1.0//EN" "http://www.apple.com/DTDs/PropertyList-1.0.dtd">
<plist version="1.0">
<dict>
  <key>workouts</key>
    <dict>
      <key>NSStringLocalizedFormatKey</key>
      <string>%1$#@number@</string>
      <key>number</key>
      <dict>
        <key>NSStringFormatSpecTypeKey</key>
        <string>NSStringPluralRuleType</string>
        <key>NSStringFormatValueTypeKey</key>
        <string>@</string>
        <key>one</key>
        <string>%2$@ Workout!</string>
        <key>other</key>
        <string>%2$@ Workouts!</string>
      </dict>
    </dict>
  </dict>
</plist>
```

The `resultString` is `13,456 Workouts!` in this example. If you change `number = 1`, the `resultString` will be `1 Workout!`